# Using LauncherPro lost usb connection notification

Tags: htc-sense, usb-connection-mode

In HTC Sense you get a little widget that indicates that you have USB connectivity to a computer and lets you change the mode (charge/storage/etc) is there a similar tool that is not part of HTC Sense which can run in LauncherPro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that thingy in the **notification bar** that upon touching let's you chose your desired mode -- that's still there with Launcher Pro as it has nothing to do with Sense and Launcher Pro has nothing to do with your notification area (unless of course you decide to disable it)